# problem of indexing and sorting in barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I have extracted `X` and `Y` from my dataframe as follows:
`X` is `UInt64Index([19, 35, 29, 10, 5, 9, 45, 72, 3, 18], dtype='uint64')` 
and `Y` is `array([14336,  6812,  4265,  3857,  2960,  1986,  1730,  1233,  1128, 841])`.

Now I want to use `sns.barplot` to plot `X` vs. `Y`. That means in the plot I must see that e.g. `X=19` has the highest related value in `Y` which is `14336`.

When I use

```
ax=sns.barplot(X, Y)
# add the values of each x index on the bars in the barplot
for p, q in zip(ax.patches, Y):
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
        p.get_height()*(1.01),
        "{}".format(q),
        ha = 'center'
       )
```

I see the following plot:
[image]

Unfortunately I see different values! Apparently `sns.barplot` sort the `X` (from small to large value), however it does not change the related value in `Y`.

Does anyone has a clue to solve this?

thanks!

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Hi Artem. I have added the complete code. As you see from the plot, 19 (in x axis) has the highest value (the bar is the largest), however, the value above the bar is 1986 (instead of 14336).  Other example is for X=18 (which is the last number of X) the corresponding value is 841 (in Y array), however, in the plot is 2960. (actually, 841 is now consider the corresponding value for 72 in X axis.)

Comment: Thanks, upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend on what you want to show,

#### all bars ordered by size

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


X = np.array([19, 35, 29, 10, 5, 9, 45, 72, 3, 18])
Y = np.array([14336,  6812,  4265,  3857,  2960,  1986,  1730,  1233,  1128, 841])

ax = sns.barplot(X,Y, order=X)
for p, q in zip(ax.patches, Y):
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
        p.get_height()*(1.01),
        "{}".format(q),
        ha = 'center'  )
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### all bars ordered by x value

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


X = np.array([19, 35, 29, 10, 5, 9, 45, 72, 3, 18])
Y = np.array([14336,  6812,  4265,  3857,  2960,  1986,  1730,  1233,  1128, 841])

ax = sns.barplot(X,Y)
for p, q in zip(ax.patches, Y[np.argsort(X)]):
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
        p.get_height()*(1.01),
        "{}".format(q),
        ha = 'center'  )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used strings instead of integers for X, and ordered it manually.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


print "hello"

X = ["19", "35", "29", "10", "5", "9", "45", "72", "3", "18"]

order = ["19", "35", "29", "10", "5", "9", "45", "72", "3", "18"]

Y = [14336,  6812,  4265,  3857,  2960,  1986,  1730,  1233,  1128, 841]

ax=sns.barplot(X,Y, order=order)
# add the values of each x index on the bars in the barplot
for p, q in zip(ax.patches, Y):
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
        p.get_height()*(1.01),
        "{}".format(q),
        ha = 'center'
       )

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess even the strings are sorted by the sns.barplot. Because on the x axis I see (10, 18, 19, 29, 3, 35, 45, 5, 72, 9). For this reason, I still obtain not fully correct plot. I mean on each bar, the written number is not correct.

Comment: I think the edit solves it, possibly even without changing the X to strings, but just using the order argument.

Comment: great!  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I think you can achieve your resulting plot much simpler. Why do you calculate separate X and Y arrays; seaborn is made to work with pandas. Why do you calculate your text positions? They're already there:

Suppose you have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([14336, 6812, 4265, 3857, 2960, 1986, 1730, 1233, 1128, 841], index=[19, 35, 29, 10, 5, 9, 45, 72, 3, 18])
```

Then you can plot it directly with

```
ax=sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=0, data=df, order=df.index)
```

And printing the values on top of the bars like you did would just be

```
for i, y in enumerate(df[0]):
    ax.text(i, 1.01*y, str(y), ha='center')
```

However, I'd use a constant gap between bars and values, not one which scales with the barheight...

**edit:**
My opinion for a better alternative to calculating separate X and Y like in the question:

You can extract a subseries from a dataframe. Suppose your original dataframe is called `df`:

```
s = df[df.is_attributed==1].app.value_counts()
```

And the plot command changes a little to

```
ax = sns.barplot(x=s.index, y=s, order=s.index)
```

...and so of course does the text loop:

```
for i, y in enumerate(s):
    ax.text(i, 1.01*y, str(y), ha='center')
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.  Basically I brought the simplified version of my problem here. X and Y are both extracted from a dataframe under some condition. Consider a Dataframe `df` which has two features (1. app, 2.is_attributed). Then I constructed X and Y as follows: `X= df[df.is_attributed==1]['app'].value_counts()[:10].index` and `Y=df[df.is_attributed==1]['app'].value_counts()[:10].values`. Thats the reason I did not used DataFrame to plot it. However, I like the way you provide the solution, especially the last part for printing values on top of bars :)

Comment: Alright, understood. However,  let me please give two further hints: 1. Index is sth which remains in a subdstaframe or a subseries - you don't have to save it manually 2. "Never do bracket chaining" is one of pandas most famous rules. Use `df.loc` instead if needed.